# JodaTime round Duration/Period to nearest minutes/hours/days/weeks/months/years

Tags: java, rounding, jodatime

If I have two instants in JodaTime, for example

```
DateTime then=new DateTime(0);
DateTime now=DateTime.now();
```

and I want to get the number of years between these two dates, I can do

```
new Period(then,now).getYears();
```

or

```
Years.yearsBetween(then,now);
```

But the problem is that if the interval is not an exact number of years, both of these methods will return the floor of the number of years.  So for example, of you have two instants which are two years and 11 months apart, it will still return "0" years.

Is there any way JodaTime provides to get the rounded number of years,months,etc?

The purpose of this is that I wish to display durations in a human friendly format, for example

```
1 year, 11 months, 30 days, 1 hour -> 2 years.
6 days 4 hours 1 minute -> 1 week
4 hours 18 minutes 5 seconds -> 4 hours
```

And so I'd like to display properly rounded amounts.

I think I could probably check whether the end of the interval is closer to N Units in the future or N+1 Units, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How about adding six months to your period before rounding it off?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I ended up writing my own function to choose between N and N+1 units based on which is closer in absolute time.